# Changing the commit author for Git/Github on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python, git, pycharm

**Problem:**

I cant get the correct username to show up for commits on github.

**Background:**

I first had a Github account for personal use that was just to mess around and become familiar with it. Now I'm in a college course that required me to create a new Github account. We are using pycharm for python programs in my class. When I commit and push to my repository on my new Github account the commit log shows my personal account username.

**Attempts To Fix:**

I've tried the:

`git config --global user.name "yourname"`

then I tested that the username was correct with:

`git config --global user.name`

I did the same with email and password to see if that made a difference.
When that didn't work I looked around on google to see what I could find. People said to remove and re add credentials with the windows credential manager. I did that too and still no luck.

I'm willing to delete my personal account if that's what needs to be done I just need this second account to show the correct username when pushing because the professor won't grade the code unless you use your school username.

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, github performs the comparison of the user via the e-mail address.

So try:

Go to Github.com -> Setting -> E-mail
Add the Email address you used in your .gitconfig to your account.

---

Additional you can do conditional commits

## Conditional Git Config

Your global git config `.gitconfig`

```
[user]
  email = priv-mail@example.com

# on Windows for all directories below p:/cy/* use the .corp.gitconfig config
[includeIf "gitdir/i:p:/cy/**"]
  path = ./.corp.gitconfig
```

Your secondary git config `.corp.gitconfig`

```
[user]
  email = corp-mail@example.com
```

you can test if the right config value ...

```
git config --show-origin --get user.email
```

The official documentation can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes)

Comment: The top part of this was the fix for my problem. I retried entering my username email and password back into the git config global and it works now somehow. Thank you!